# Как заставить urllib3 возвращать 307/301 ответы сервера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

При попытке получить ответ сервера по URL, который СОВЕРШЕННО ТОЧНО редиректит по 307 коду (по 301 скорее всего тоже), urllib3 возвращает 200-й ответ сервера, что дезинформирует. 
Нужно знать, когда страница возвращает 307-й ответ. Как быть?

Ниже привожу часть кода, которая у меня за это дело отвечает. Пробовал через Requests, та же история.

```
from urllib.request import *
from urllib.error import *

    def __init__(self, urls):
        super().__init__()

        self.urls = urls

    def run(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            try:
                code = urlopen(url).getcode()
            except HTTPError as e:
                # Пусть будет исключение
                code = str(e)
```

Comment: Ваш код не может давать 200 код, там где 307. Воспользуйтесь wireshark и сами увидите.

Comment: Или Вы хотите exeption там где будет не 200? Его не будет, если сами не сгенерируете по условию.

Comment: как минимум я добавил бы print(code) для прояснения ситуации.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич у меня там сигналы для вывода этого дела в UI PyQt

Comment: Учтите, что 307 ответ сервера это НЕ HTTPError в python коде. Это штатная ситуация.

Comment: HTTPError у Вас возникнет, например по Timeout... Или при неработающем DNS. Но не при штатном ответе сервера с кодом.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич я это понимаю. Если бы была ошибкой, я мог бы реализовать то, что мне нужно через обработку исключений. Но в том-то и дело, что он тупо возвращает 200-й ответ.

Comment: Если через requests - использовать опцию `allow_redirects=False`, тогда автоматического перехода по редиректу не будет: [Redirection and History](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Вот скриншот. [https://ibb.co/fOmDi0]

Comment: @insolor если Вы вместо комментария оформите своё сообщение как ответ, то я хотел бы выбрать его ответом на вопрос.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110498/is-there-an-easy-way-to-request-a-url-in-python-and-not-follow-redirects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если использовать модуль `requests`, то при запросе можно указать параметр `allow_redirects=False`, тогда автоматическое перенаправление выполняться не будет:

```
r = requests.get('http://ya.ru/')
print(r)  # <Response [200]>
print(r.url)  # https://ya.ru/ - автоматически перенаправлено на https

r = requests.get('http://ya.ru/', allow_redirects=False)
print(r)  # <Response [302]>
```

Документация: [Redirection and History](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Answer (score 3):

Модуль urllib [автоматически ходит по перенаправлениям](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c53aaec793e018edef4e72a3edbd338b10db10aa/Doc/library/urllib.request.rst#L285). Не знаю, по какому недоразумению отсутствует штатная возможность отключения этого, но можно написать свой отключающий handler:

```
class NoRedirectHandler(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        return fp

    http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302
```

Потом создаём opener с этим handler'ом:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(NoRedirectHandler())
```

Теперь можно отправлять свои запросы с помощью метода `opener.open`, но если хочется отключить обработку перенаправлений по умолчанию везде и сразу, то можно установить его по умолчанию:

```
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

Теперь редиректы обрабатываться не будут:

```
r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ya.ru/')
print(r.code)                 # → 302
print(r.url)                  # → http://ya.ru/
print(r.headers['Location'])  # → https://ya.ru/
```